# UIView's height not taking into account the Navigation Bar when using Storyboards

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, frame, uistoryboard

I've seen questions that look like this but the misunderstanding of people asking them was that they checked their `UIView`'s height on `viewDidLoad:` and when they checked it again on `viewDidAppear:` the result was as expected.

So I'm checking (and most importantly using the value for some animations) and the height of the view I get doesn't take into account the `UINavigationBar` present. The thing to note is that I'm using a `UIStoryboard` and `autolayout`.

Any hints of why I'm getting the height of the whole screen and how can I get the correct value?

Thank you

Comment: check Under Top Bars is checked in Attribute inspector

Comment: @the1pawan nothing changed

Comment: tried to log height with checked n unchecked Under Top Bars, can you provide any extra info

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the translucency of your navigation bar to NO in your storyboard file and get the frame of the view from the view's `-(void)didLayoutSubviews` method or the view controller's `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. These get called when a view's frames have been updated and the view's layout is finalised (and on refreshes, so you might want to put in a check for the first run).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking the height when user begins interacting, so way after those methods were called